# Is there a way to override a constructor function from a reference in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, closures

Let's say I have the following code, which **I CANNOT modify**

```
var namespace = {};

function() {
    var MyConstructorFunction = function() {
        alert("default behavior");
    };

    namespace.MyConstructorFunction = MyConstructorFunction;

    setTimeout(function() {
        var instance = new MyConstructorFunction();
    }, 1000)
}();
```

I would like to externally add some code in the global scope from which I only have access to `namespace` for making `instance` to be constructed with `alert("custom behavior")`;

Just to clarify my intentions, let's say I could think of these two aproaches:

```
namespace.MyConstructorFunction = function() {
    alert("custom behavior");
};
```

or

```
namespace.MyConstructorFunction.prototype.constructor = function() {
    alert("custom behavior");
};
```

But obviously they don't work. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you're saying you'd want to change the constructor that's invoked in the `setTimeout`, then no. The variable used there is local to the immediately invoked function. You can't touch that variable, and the function itself is immutable, so there's really no way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the prototype chain to override methods in a namespace.

```
// create an object that inherits from namespace
var o = Object.create(namespace);

// Override the MyConstructorFunction property
o.MyConstructorFunction = function ()  {
    alert("custom behavior");
}
```

And you can reuse the namespace token

```
namespace = o;
```

Or you can use a different namespace if you would prefer.

Object.create is an ES5 feature which cannot be emulated entirely in ES3, but in this use case it should work with a basic [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

---

**But** I understand you want to call a different constructor from the setTimeout, **which in this example is impossible**. The function references a local variable which cannot be altered. While you can change the global behaviour of an object like in this example, you cannot alter the variables inside a closure except through functions that can see those variables. If the function were to reference the globally scoped variable and not the locally scoped variable you would be in luck.

i.e:

```
var namespace = {};

function() {
    var MyConstructorFunction = function() {
        alert("default behavior");
    };

    namespace.MyConstructorFunction = MyConstructorFunction;

    setTimeout(function() {
        var instance = new namespace.MyConstructorFunction(); // reference global
    }, 1000)
}();
```

Comment: This doesn't affect the assignment to the variable `instance` that OP is asking about. And setting `o.prototype` doesn't have any effect on inheritance. `o` will not inherit the rest of the items from `namespace`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an instance, you can't override constructor. And in a real application, you don't want to, for security reasons.

But you can override or add specific methods:

```
var F = function() {
  this.foo = 'bar';
}

var f = new F();
typeof f.foo; // "string"

f.foo = function() { return 'Bar' };
typeof f.foo; // "function"
```